# Wavelength of standing wave in a closed-end tube?

Tags: resonance

Can anyone explain the answer to the following multiple choice question? The answer sheet says 4 is the right answer, but I cannot seem to grasp why that is the case. I have asked my teacher and some peers but they all seem to be troubled by the question. [image]

Answer (score 1):

We introduce the closed pipe to students by telling them that the resonances occur when the pipe length is $\lambda/4$, $3\lambda/4$, $5\lambda/4$, and so on. However this is not quite correct because the antinode is not exactly at the end of the pipe, but slightly past the end in the air outside the pipe. This is known as the [end correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_correction).

Suppose we call the end correction $d$, then if the first resonance is at $x$ we have:

$$ x + d = \tfrac14 \lambda \tag{1} $$

And if the second resonance is at $y$ we have:

$$ y + d = \tfrac34 \lambda \tag{2} $$

We don't know $d$ but we can eliminate it by subtracting equation $1$ from equation $2$ to get:

$$ y - x = \tfrac12 \lambda $$

And rearranging gives:

$$ \lambda = 2(y-x) $$